# Removing a file from hard drive after it has been loaded into an SFrame or any other python data structure

Tags: python, sframe

```
data = graphlab.SFrame.read_json('mongodump.json')
```

If create the `data` variable by executing the line above, and then move or remove the file `mongodump.json`, would the variable `data` still be alive?